# Difference between return None and pass

Tags: python, python-3.x

consider my scenario, I have a method which is kind of a factory that returns me the action based on the status that I pass.

```
def factory(status):
    action = {
        1: action_1,
        2: action_2,
        3: action_3,
    }.get(status)

    return action
```

and these are the actions,

```
def action_1():
    # making db call
    action_1_db_call()

def action_2():
    # making db call
    action_2_db_call()

def action_3():
    # It will do nothing
    pass
```

I will basically do the following in the main code,

```
action = factory(1)
action()
```

So here, which is the right approach for action_3? Can I just use `pass` for this method or I should return `None`. which one is advisable and a good practice?

Comment: If all it does is pass, that *will* return none. You only need the pass because the function must have *some* body, there are other ways to write it (e.g. `action_3 = lambda: None`).

Comment: If the function has docstring, you can omit `pass` too